# test whether k elements of a set add up to a certain number

Tags: algorithm, set

Is there a way to determine if k elements of a set add up to a certain number in polynomial time?

Comment: Is k known before hand, or is it part of the input?

Comment: k is known beforehand; it could be any size

Comment: If k is known before hand (i.e independent on n) then the brute force algorithm of enumerating all k size subsets is polynomial...

Comment: @aryabhatta - why is it polynomial? Isn't it O(n-choose-k)? Isn't n-choose-k O(2^n) when k=n/2?

Comment: @wrick: If k is independent of n... so k=n/2 is not possible. And n choose k is O(n^k).

Answer (score 3):

How big is the number?

This is a variation on the subset sum problem, which is well-known and NP-complete.  However dynamic programming techniques will make it polynomial **if** the set of possible values that the subsets can take grows polynomially.  Which with general integers, isn't true.  But with numbers picked from a restricted range happens surprisingly often.